# openssl encryption without IV in laravel

Tags: laravel, php-7.4

I am creating an API using laravel 8, I want to encrypt string with IV null which is the requirement of third party API, but when I pass null in openssl function it returns null.
Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this in laravel 8. Below is the code, I tried with `''` also instead of `NULL` but still getting `null` response.

Any help would be appreciated

```
$json = json_encode($params);
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$key = env('ENCRYPTION_KEY');
return openssl_encrypt($json, $method, $key, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: A static IV is not really a great idea, but if the third party requires it, `str_repeat("\0", 16)` may be a good value to to pass in as "null" IV.

Comment: Okay. I will try your solution. Thanks

Comment: It seems you could also pass in "" or omit passing in the IV parameter at all since that's the default value, however if you omit it entirely, you'll get a warning.

Comment: I tried passing "" but didn't work